# Setting FormGroup data in MatDialog when clicking a button not working properly

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have a `MatTable`. Once I select a row from the table click on the edit button it needs to open a `MatDialog` and fill the `FormControls` from selected row's data.

Here is my function to open `MatDialog` when button click happened.

```
openEditWindow(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(MatDialogFormComponent, {
      width: '600px',
      height: '500px',
      data: {
        formHeaderText: 'Edit File Template',
        editData: this.selectedRowForEdit
      }
    });
  }
```

Here is my `MatDialogFormComponent` class.

```
export class MatDialogFormComponent implements OnInit {
// I removed some parts from the class for clarity. 
siteInsertForm = new FormGroup({
    templateName: new FormControl(),
    tagAddressFormat: new FormControl(),
    headerValueSeparator: new FormControl(),
    paramValuesCount: new FormControl(),
    paramValueSeparator: new FormControl()
  });

constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {

  }
}
```

In `MatDialog`'s HTML code I was able to successfully change the form name using data received from the MatTable Component class.

```
<h1 mat-dialog-title>{{data.formHeaderText}}</h1>
```

Above code is working without any issue. So then I try to parse the values to for Edit form.

```
ngOnInit() {
this.siteInsertForm .patchValue({
    templateName: this.editData.templateName
});
}
```

But above code is not worked.

So I tried something like this to understand what is going on here.

I implemented the AfterViewInit life cycle method in the MatDialogFormComponent class.

```
export class MatDialogFormComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit  {
// I removed some parts from the class for clarity. 

ngOnInit() {
this.siteInsertForm .patchValue({
    templateName: this.editData.templateName
});
}
ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.siteInsertForm.patchValue({
      templateName: this.data.editData.name
    });
  }

}
```

Then It showed the templateName in MatDialog and I got below error in console.

```
ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'mat-form-field-should-float: false'. Current value: 'mat-form-field-should-float: true'.
```

Any thoughts to resolve this issue ? I am using `Angular 6`

Answer (score 1):

You should use `ngAfterViewChecked` lifecycle hook

```
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.siteInsertForm .patchValue({
      templateName: this.editData.templateName
  });
}
```

> ngAfterViewChecked is a lifecycle hook that is called after the default change >detector has completed checking a component's view for changes.

Comment: can you create a stackblitz?

Comment: Once  I implement the code inside the `ngAfterViewChecked`, it starts to work. Do you think this is good practice?

Comment: Yes it is. It's a lifecycle hook that is called after the default change detector has completed checking a component's view for changes.